# Customize server soap fault string

Tags: java, soap, jboss

I have a SOAP Webservice running on JBoss EAP 6.4.
If I submit the following request:

http://localhost:8180/myService/MyService?wsdl=%foobar

The server generates a standard SoapFault like this:

```
<soap:Envelope>
 <soap:Body>
   <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Exception occurred while trying to process http://localhost:8180/myService/MyService</faultstring>
   </soap:Fault>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now I would like to show my own faultstring. At least I want to hide the hostname.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Though it depends on which SOAP library you are using, like axis or axis2 or Xfire or Spring or something else. But most of SOAP liberary has concept called as `MessageHandler` and those are more of processors where the Incoming and Outgoing SOAP messages could be intercepted and modified if needed.

Here are some ready links to understand the SOAPHandlers.

https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/jax-ws-soap-handler-example/

I hope this gives you some pointers. Update the question or add comment if you need further specific information.

Comment: I know the concept of the HandlerChain. But in this case, they have no effect because it is a SoapFault generated by the "jboss".

Comment: This may be one option, but surely not the easy one. The `myService` must have mapped to SOAP generic `servlet`, you could extend it and change the `servlet` config to your overwritten `servlet` and modify the code to overwrite the response payload, just ignore my response if there is configuration exist for same that I'm not aware.